# Gitlab change redirect for nonexistent paths away from login page

Tags: redirect, nginx, authentication, gitlab

Using omnibus gitlab 9.2.

Action: As a non-logged-in user, attempt a request for a public project that doesn't exist (at least not publicly).

Result: Receive a 302 redirect to /users/sign_in from nginx.

What I'd like to see: Receive a 302 redirect to /public (or wherever, for that matter)

What I've tried without success: Adding this to gitlab.rb:

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "try_files $uri $uri/ /public;\n\nfastcgi_intercept_errors on;\n\n"
```

I couldn't find the explicit redirect in any nginx conf, so I guess it's in Rails. I'll peruse that code.

This is actually a custom HA configuration with the gitlab nodes behind haproxy fronts. I thought about possibly doing something on the fronts, but couldn't come up with anything.

Thanks!

Edit:

I see now that replacing the unmatched_route line in routes.rb with:

get '*unmatched_route', to: redirect('/public'), via: :all

does what I need, but I'd of course want to make that change persistent. Is *that* possible?